# PHP to Python XML API

Tags: php, python, curl

I have an API written in PHP I want to code it in Python, but I even can`t log in, nor to use the service.

The PHP API uses curl to handle requests, in python I`ll use requests module:

```
class CURL {    function doRequest($method, $url, $vars) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
        }
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($data) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            return curl_error($ch);
        }   }       function post($url, $vars) {
        return $this->doRequest('POST', $url, $vars);   } }
```

The thins is simple and clear as I make the request:

```
import requests

response = request.get(url)
response.content

private $methods = array(
    'Login'=>'/Login',
    'Logout'=>'/Logout',
    'Synchronize'=>'/Synchronize',
);
```

When I try to use /Login method from PHP it says:

```
loginMethod = url + '/Login'
response = requests.get(loginMethod)
response.content
```

It says:

```
>     '\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n  <head>\r\n   
> <title>Service</title>\r\n    <style>BODY { color: #000000;
> background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px;
> margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em;
> padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold;
> text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight:
> bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699;
> font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 {
> background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color:
> #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:
> 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color:
> #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space:
> -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right:
> 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold;
> background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid;
> border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color:
> #e5e5cc;}</style>\r\n  </head>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <div id="content">\r\n      <p class="heading1">Service</p>\r\n      
> 
> <p>Method not allowed.</p>\r\n    </div>\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>'
```

In addition dosn`t let met to access even to login page, however it works in PHP

```
/**************************************/
# doRequest(String:$var,String:$method)#
# $var request string                  #
# $method servise method               #
/**************************************/

private function doRequest($var,$method='')
{
    $curl= new CURL();
    $return = $curl->post($this->URL.$method,$var);
if ($this->verbose){
    echo "\n--\nRequest: $this->URL$method\n",$var,"\nResponse:\n",$return,"\n";
}
    return $return;
}

/******************************************/
# Login()                                  #
# makes Login request and save sesion vars #
# return bool                              #
/******************************************/

public function Login()
{
    if($this->UserSession)
    {
        $this->Logout();
    }
    $User = new SimpleXMLElement('<User></User>');
    $User->addChild('Name',$this->User);
    $User->addChild('Hash',$this->Password);
    try
    {
        $data=$this->doRequest($User->asXML(),$this->methods['Login']);
        $Session= new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $this->UserSession=$Session->UserSession;
        $this->UserToken=$Session->UserToken;
        $Session = new SimpleXMLElement('<Session></Session>');
        $Session->addChild('UserSession',$this->UserSession);
        $Session->addChild('UserToken',$this->UserToken);
        $this->SessionXML=$Session->asXML();    
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo($e->getMessage());
        $this->UserSession=false;
        return false;
    }
    if(in_array($this->UserSession,$this->errors))
    {
    $this->errorCode = $this->UserSession;
        $this->UserSession=false;
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: I have to send somehow a requests with Name and Hash as their attributes to get the token, so how do I add new XML tag into an URL request?

Comment: Hey I am also working on the same script.Were you able to find the solution of your own problem?